# Singularity models of the Ricci flow

Tags: partial-differential-equations, riemannian-geometry, singularity-theory, ricci-flow

I faced this sentence in my studies on Ricci flow:

**The Bryant soliton is a singularity model for the degenerate neckpinch.**

**Q1**: What is the definition and meaning of singularity model? Can one model all the singularities of the Ricci flow by solitons?

**Q2**: What is intuition of the degenerate neckpinch?

I need the answers of these questions Immediate. Can anyone help me?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: cross post: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/133197/singularity-models-of-the-ricci-flow

Answer (score 2):

*There is an answer I have from earlier lecture notes, it helped me to understand.*

Let $(\mathcal{M},h)$ a closed Riemannian manifold. One can develop the metric $h$ by:
$$\frac{\partial}{\partial t}h=-2\; \mathfrak{Rc}(h)$$ a weak parabolic system known as
*Ricci flow*.

Now imagine under certain curvature conditions on initial $h$, it is possible to prove *normalized convergence* to a round metric, hence say a lot about the topology of $\mathcal{M}$. **But** for a large set of initial metrics the *flow will become singular* in finite time before converging to any smooth limiting metric (*exciting!*).

Apparently this happens when the curvature blows up on certain regions of the manifold $\mathcal{M}$ and the *standard* short-time existence result for Ricci flow says that *if the flow becomes singular at some finite time* $T<\infty$ then
$$\lim \sup_{t\rightarrow T}\ \max_{x\in $\mathcal{M})}\vert \mathfrak{Rc}(x,t) \vert=\infty$$

In order to analyze these *singularities*, one follows the conventional singular analysis from non-linear PDEs and does a *blow-up* at the singularity using the *scaling symmetry* of the equation. Depending on how much compactness is at hand, one can extract a *singularity model* (re. your question) from a sequence of such blow-ups, which will usually have a better geometry than the original Ricci flow.

Indeed, if one has a good knowledge about the possible *singularity models*, then one is able to understand the structure of the singularity formation and see how to *do surgery* while controlling the geometry and the topology of the manifold, thus arriving at the so-called *Ricci flow with surgeries*.

It would take very long continuing on this and also *neckpinching of Ricci flow* [go here](http://www.ma.utexas.edu/users/danknopf/HsinchuSurvey.pdf).